# Аккумулятор ограничивает ресурсы процессора при низком заряде

Tags: пк

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Ноутбук Acer ex-215-51g-349T. Процессор core i3-10110u. При работе аккумулятора как только заряд падает до 30% частота процессора ограничивается 0,39Ггц. Работать невозможно. В Acer толкового ничего не ответили. В планах электропитания все параметры на максималке. В Биосе нет никаких параметров, которые можно было бы изменить. Биос обновил, драйвера тоже.

Comment: Нечто похожее было с MSI буком, концов не находили. Оказалось, что стоит родная утилита (может быть, Dragon Center, давно это было), в ней свой план электропитания...

Comment: @MBo и что же делать?

Comment: Ну я к тому, что на всякий случай поискать в автозагрузке или в процессах что-то типа Acer ePower Management (точно не знаю)

Answer (score 0):

При отключении питания у тебя ставится схема питания "экономия энергии". Можно зайти в панель управления, поставить в параметре "Категория крупные значки", перейти в электропитание и поставить схему "сбалансированная". Ещё там же можно зайти в настройки схемы энергоэкономии ->изменить доп.параметры питания -> управление питанием процессора -> (мин - 5%) (макс - 10%). Дальше найти PCI  Express - управление питанием состояния связи - значение откл.(это делаем в схеме энергосбережения). Если вторая схема ставиться авто то второй способ лучше.